# Optimal algorithm for cache with expire

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, caching

I need simple cache structure (in python, but it doesn't really matter), with some specific requirements:

1. Up to several millions of small objects (100 bytes on average)
2. Speed is the key (both put and get), I'd expect operation times at about few microseconds
3. Only one thread accessing this - so it can be all just in memory (do not need persistence)
4. Keys are MD5 hashes (if it matters)
5. There's an expiration time, global for the cache - every key should be removed from the cache after expiration time, counting from the time of first put

Now, the point is how to implement expiration - as everything other can be done using simple dictionary. The simplest solution - to iterate all data regularly and remove expired keys - could lock whole cache for too long. It could be improved by iterating parts of the data with every cleanup process - but still it will take some time (or won't clean it fast enough). Also removing keys one by one looks like the waste of CPU - as they could be removed in batches (don't have to be removed just after expiration - we can afford some extra RAM for keeping expired keys a little bit longer).

Checking keys during the retrieve is not enough (although it should be done nevertheless, to not return expired keys) - as many keys can be never retrieved and then they will stay forever (or just too long).

Most answers for that problem suggest using memcached, but I think this will be waste of CPU, especially as I keep objects which can be put to the dictionary by the reference, but using memcached they would have to be (de)serialized.

I have some idea how to implement this: split data into time slices, having actually several dictionaries - for example, if expire time is 60 seconds, then we have (at most) 4 dictonaries and every 20 seconds we add new one - where new keys are put, and remove the 4th one - where we'll have keys added over 60 seconds ago. This makes cleaning very fast at the cost of retrieve time, where you need to lookup in 4 dictionaries instead of one (and RAM usage increased by 33%).

So finally the question - which is: is there any better solution? Or maybe I'm wrong and some of mentioned solutions (removing keys one by one) would be better and faster? I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but didn't find any good solution in the net.

Answer (score 1):

Only experiments will tell you which is better.

Here's another simple idea to consider: link all the keys in a linked list in order of arrival. Each time you retrieve a key, iterate from the beginning of the list and remove all expired items, from both the list and the dictionary.

Comment: You are right I should just experiment. Already checked that retrieving from 4 dictionaries in order still fits below 1us, so it's probably the way to go. But still wondering if anybody already created similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

One implementation of a hashtable is to store a list of (key, value) for each hash value. You can extend this to storing a list of (key, insertion time, value) for each hash value. On both get and set, you can throw away expired items as you scan for the key you're interested in.

Yes, it may leave expired items in the hashtable for arbitrarily long, but only O(N) items on average, where N is the size of your hash table.

Good properties of this approach are that there's no concurrent cleanup going on, and the overhead is more or less constant.

You'll have to code this in C rather than Python if you care about speed.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Timer service (sched in Python?) that fires an event after N seconds. For every key schedule a timer event (they are pretty lightweight) and have it remove the key.

The Java counterpart is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: As I mentioned - this is one thread, and adding another one for removing keys would give as a lot synchronization problems - also, this would be much worse than just simple processing them sequentially and removing one by one.

Comment: in general polling is far less efficient than a notification. in this case, you are not only polling one object for its expiration but you are polling the entire population. good luck!

Comment: and you can use the timer notification without synchronization on the cache itself. just have it enqueue the notifications, and have your single thread once in a while drain the queue and remove the notified objects from the queue. i fail to see how examining 1,000,000 objects periodically to find say 1,000 expired objects can ever be more efficient than processing 1,000 deletions off a queue. sigh...